# Regex: timestamp + loglevel info

Tags: ruby

I want to match (timestamp + log level info)

Examples:

```
2018-02-21 17:06:00,011 DEBUG  [example]loremipsum
2018-02-21  17:06:00,011 DEBUG [example]  loremipsum 
2018-02-21 17:06:00,011   DEBUG  [example]  loremipsum
```

with:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[,.]\d{3}\s?[a-zA-Z]{4,10}
```

Problem is that I dont know if is correct, because I have sometimes 0 matches if after loglevel info (DEBUG) are more than two whitespaces, or tabs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets make this slightly more readable (using the regex you provided)

```
date_regex = /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/
time_regex = /\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[,.]\d{3}/
log_level_regex = /[a-zA-Z]{4,10}/
regex = /#{date_regex}\s#{time_regex}\s?#{log_level_regex}/
```

The error in your regex is the wrong use of quantifiers. You're using `\s` (exactly 1 whitespace), and `\s?` (1 or 0 whitespaces).

You want to use `\s+` (1 or more whitespaces), or `\s*` (0 or more whitespaces) instead.

this would result in:

```
/#{date_regex}\s+#{time_regex}\s*#{log_level_regex}/
# or if you prefer the not so readable version:
/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[,.]\d{3}\s*[a-zA-Z]{4,10}/
```

I'd suggest you take a look at [regex cheat sheet quantifiers section](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#quantifiers).

Answer (score 0):

```
log.split($/).map { |line| line[/\A.*?(?=\[)/].strip }
#⇒ ["2018-02-21 17:06:00,011 DEBUG",
#   "2018-02-21  17:06:00,011 DEBUG",
#   "2018-02-21 17:06:00,011   DEBUG"]
```